# picking last records inserted into table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I have inserted 4 records into table1, and then 5 records and then 3 records.
Now I want to pick up last 3 records or say any number of records but inserted at last. How I  will get those ?

Actually scenario is that in gridview 1 user would select say 3 records by help of checkbox field and then these 3 records will be inserted in to table1 and then store procedure will pick these last inserted 3 reocrds and assign it to RDLC report. All things are done but just don't know how to pick last inserted any number of records.

Comment: You have to keep track of the last inserted records manually, since the DB cannot do that for you.

Comment: can you show ur table design?

Comment: Do you have a row-id or timestamps?

Comment: you can use limit keyword in sql query

Comment: do you have created_date column in your table, if no create one with default value getdate().

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a table is an unordered set of rows. There is no way to ask SQL Server which row was inserted last unless you are doing so in the same batch as the insert. For example, if your table has an IDENTITY column, you can say:

INSERT dbo.table(column) values (...)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();

But that too will give you the last first identity column.

What you can do here is that you can take the help of timestamp and define that in a separate column of the table.

ALTER TABLE dbo.table ADD DateInserted DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Define stored procedure with the @lastrows count that you will store in your service layer to call.

CREATE PROC sp_GetLastInsertedRows(@lastrows int)
AS

;WITH x AS (SELECT *, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateInserted DESC)
   FROM dbo.table)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE r <= N;

This way you get the last N number of rows inserted in the last transaction.

Comment: Let me add two points: Not only is there no order to the rows according to the SQL standard, there is also no order to the columns.
        
And to come back to the original question: You __can't do it nor should you!__ If you need it you must provide the means by adding the relevant information to your table design like a rowNumber or an insertionDateTime column.         But in many real DBMS systems you can work around the standerd and use their rowIDs etc..

Answer (score 0):

you can use below menioned query

```
 SELECT column_name FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: limit is not fixed, it could be any number

Comment: opps... then you have to create a coloum for created date and try to filter recorde based on created date

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you're going to need something a bit more flexible. Right now you may have just one user, and right now you may be running the report immediately after executing the `INSERT` statements, but what you really need to know is what rows are new since the last time you looked.

One good way of doing this is adding a `DATETIME NULL` field to the row; let's call it `processed_date`. This field will be updated by the stored procedure that picks them up for the report. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
INTO #report_tbl
WHERE processed_date IS NULL

UPDATE tbl1
SET processed_date = GETDATE()
WHERE id_field IN (
    SELECT id_field
    FROM #report_tbl
)
```

Now you are sure to pick up the rows that "haven't been looked at."